# Database Triggers Java Application

Tags: java, database

Is there any way that when I insert a record in database manually and it execute some Java code ? Anything is acceptable like webservice or rmi ?

I am using MySQL but generic(for all databases) solution would be perfect.

Comment: MySQL but genaric solution would be perfect.

Comment: If only there were a generic solution.

Comment: Oracle and Java DB has a way to call a java static method. MySQL you wont be able to do.

Comment: @shazin please share that way, I may change my database.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB supports calling java code from sql.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#N1240C

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table called jobs and a cron job which runs every minute. The cron job would read jobs and if you find records, execute whatever needs to be executed and remove the row from the table.